# vim error 'E45: 'readonly' option is set' on a file with write permission Debian 9 vim 8.0.707

Tags: vim, vimrc

I wonder why I have the error in title while the edited file have write bit enabled and the good user :

```
# ls -l /etc/hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 693 Nov 15 09:46 /etc/hosts
# whoami
root
```

Any idea ? A setting ? A bug ?

Tried `set readonly=noro`, but I get

```
E474: Invalid argument: readonly=noro
```

from `vim vimrc`

Tried :

```
set noro:verb set readonly?
```

and

```
set noreadonly
```

without any change, nor error

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward explanation would be that `'readonly'` was explicitly set, either via `:set readonly` or by opening the file with `:view /etc/hosts`. You should then be able to avoid the E45 with `:write!`.

Comment: Tried `set readonly=noro`, bu I get **E474: Invalid argument: readonly=** in vimrc

Comment: That would be `:set noreadonly`. The fact that you've attempted to put this into your .vimrc hints that you have not much of a clue what you're doing... this doesn't bode well for productive troubleshooting.

Comment: I don't try to type this each time in command mode, but modify my vimrc

Comment: And with `set noreadonly` in vimrc, still the problem

Comment: Can you force-write (with `:w!`)? If not, this really is a filesystem permission problem, not a Vim setting.

Comment: `:set noreadonly` works great, but not the vimrc config

Comment: The `'readonly'` option is buffer-local; you cannot set it in your .vimrc. Maybe `:setlocal readonly?` can tell you where this got set from.